# How can I write a binary response in php bit by bit?

Tags: php, stream, bit

I want to output an mp3 file on the fly with php so that I can experiment with using html5 audio tags for voip calls. I intend to use an mp3 audio tag in the html document that points to my php file which generate mp3 data on the fly. Parts of the mp3 headers are encoded in just 2 bits. I have looked into `pack()` but it appears to only support packing into bytes. I could group the headers together into bits of 8 but I would really rather be able to write to the stream bit by bit. Is there a way to do this in php or will I have to write a java/c++ server to get that kind of low level control?

**UPDATE**

So after some research it seems that due to the limitations (practical limitations) of tcp/ip and the way the php pipeline works, subverting a byte by byte transfer isn't really feasible using php.

Comment: You cannot send 2 bit. You need create atleast one byte to send. What is the rest of the byte with those bits?

Comment: With a large file/stream it wouldn't be unreasonable to break the file up into byes but I don't want to run into the problem of ending my stream and having to make a random 7 bits to send off say my last lonely bit.

Comment: Why do you want to send individual bits? It doesn't make sense. Most protocols, including TCP only allow sending one byte at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this: Take "one" random byte, and set wanted bits, pack.

```
$random_byte = mt_rand(0, 255); // it's not real one byte. But pack would truncate to it.
$last_bit = 1; //
$random_byte_with_last_bit = $random_byte | $last_bit;
var_dump(sprintf('%08b', $random_byte_with_last_bit));
$result = pack('C', $random_byte_with_last_bit);
```